# How many 11 digit lottery tickets produced from a set {1,...,80} have all 7 winning numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, lotteries

11 digit lottery tickets are produced from the set {1,2,3,...,80}. I understand there to be C(80,11) total lottery tickets. Seven different numbers from the set {1,2,3,...,80} are chosen to be winning numbers. How many different lottery tickets can contain all seven of the winning numbers?

Comment: A winning lottery ticket will have 7 determined numbers. How many are left to choose?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if an 11-number ticket contains 7 out of 7 winning numbers, how many ways are there to complete the ticket from among the 73 non-winning numbers?

Comment: I think I see what you are hinting at. There would be C(73,4) ways to complete the winning tickets with the remaining 73 numbers.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I appreciate your input, thanks.